# Where is the best place to make calculations outside the render method in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a render method in my container component like this:

```
 render() {
        const { validationErrors } = this.state

        const { errorsText, errorsFields} = validationErrors.reduce(
            (acc, error) => {
                acc.errorsText.push(error.text)
                acc.errorsFields[error.field.toLowerCase()] = true
                return acc
            },
            {
                errorsText: [],
                errorsFields: {},
            },
        )

        return (
            <MyViewComponent
                errorsText={errorsText}
                errorsFields={errorsFields}
            />
        )
    }
```

As you can see every render there are some computations happens (returned array and object with the new values), then I pass it into my child component as a props. I have a feeling that this is a wrong pattern. We should keep render function 'pure'. Isn't it? The question is: Where is the best place for making such computations outside the render?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this were a [functional component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) (which I highly recommend you use in the future, by the way), you'd be able to use the 'hook' `useEffect` to recalculate `errorsText` and `errorsField` whenever `this.state.validationErrors` changes, and *only* when it changes.

For your Class Component, however, I assume at some point you set `this.state.validationErrors`. What you should do is create a method that runs your reducer and stores `errorsText` and `errorsField` to state, then place a call to this method after each point you set `this.state.validationErrors`. Then, remove the logic in the `render` method and replace `errorsText` and `errorsField` with `this.state.errorsText` and `this.state.errorsField` respectively.

Doing this will ensure you only ever run your reducer when necessary (i.e. when `this.state.validationErrors` changes).

Your component would end up looking something like this:

```js
class MyComponent extends Component {
  ...
  someCallback() {
    const validationErrors = someFunctionThatReturnsErrors();

    // We do the logic here, because we know that validationErrors
    // could have changed value
    const { errorsText, errorsFields } = validationErrors.reduce(
      (acc, error) => {
        acc.errorsText.push(error.text);
        acc.errorsFields[error.field.toLowerCase()] = true;
        return acc;
      }, {
        errorsText: [],
        errorsFields: {},
      },
    );

    // Put everything in the state
    this.setState({
      validationErrors,   // you may not even need to set this if it's not used elsewhere`
      errorsText,
      errorsFields
    });
  }
  ...
  render() {
    const {
      errorsText,
      errorsFields
    } = this.state;

    return (
      <MyViewComponent
      errorsText={errorsText}
      errorsFields={errorsFields}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is pure, as it has no side effects.

As long as this does not create performance issues I see no problem with this. If it does create performance issues, you should look into memoizing the reduce. If you were using hooks you could use the built-in `React.useMemo` for this. While using class version you could look into something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/memoize-one